# NextAuth not showing signIn page

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When I enter http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signIn I get
Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js

I created new next.js latest app and install NextAuth and firebase still get the same error.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.5.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "firebase": "^10.3.1",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

route.ts

```
import { authConfig } from "@/app/lib/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authConfig);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

folder structure:
[image]